# Image from ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE Rotated

Tags: java, android, image

I am trying to simply get an image from a phone's camera. Surprisingly, it returns rotated. I've scoured the internet for fixes and came across many solutions using ExifInterface, but it only works sometimes. It gets the orientation wrong seemingly randomly, as I merely recompile and see different results. I have found some people saying this is a fault of the class itself being bugged.

I found other solutions that require like two additional libraries and more java files to do the job, but that just seems ridiculous (and I am avoiding additional packages). How come images are rotated in the first place (in storage they are perfectly fine), and how hard can it possibly be to fix the issue? Also - rotating the Image View also works (and seems much easier than literally creating a rotated image), but I need to know by *how much* to rotate the view.

EDIT---- I realized that the image is consistently rotated 270 degrees clockwise from the orientation the image was taken in (inside the intent) if the back camera was used, and 90 degrees if the front camera was used. Thus I only really need a way to find out this orientation.

Intent called here:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = setUpPhotoFile();
            mCurrentPhotoPath = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            photoFile = null;
            mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);

        } else {
            Toast noStorage = Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot access mounted storage.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            noStorage.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Bitmap created here:

```
private void setPic() {
   /* Get the size of the ImageView */
    int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
    int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

    /* Get the size of the image */
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    /* Figure out which way needs to be reduced less */
    int scale = 1;
    if (photoH > targetH|| photoW > targetW) {
        scale = Math.max(
                (int)Math.pow(2, (int) Math.ceil(Math.log(targetW /
                (double) photoW)) / Math.log(0.5)),

                (int)Math.pow(2, (int) Math.ceil(Math.log(targetH /
                (double) photoH)) / Math.log(0.5)));
        ;
    }


    /* Set bitmap options to scale the image decode target */
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scale;

    /* Decode the JPEG file into a Bitmap */
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);

     /*-----------How should I rotate bitmap/mImageView to correct orientation?*/

    /* Associate the Bitmap to the ImageView */
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I have found is this one:

https://www.samieltamawy.com/how-to-fix-the-camera-intent-rotated-image-in-android/

I post the link because I don't want all the credit.

Sami Eltamawy has written a function that rotate the image if its need to be rotated.

I try the code and is working on my devices that the image got rotated.

Comment: It's not work on Samsung device